# Probability cards question

Tags: probability, combinatorics

What is the probability that the first card is spades given that the second and third cards are spades?

Attempt: Use Bayes' rule to calculate $P(E_1|E_2E_3)$

- $E_1$ = first card is spade
- $E_2$ = second card is spade
- $E_3$ = third card is spade

$$ P(E_1) = \frac{13}{52} $$
$$ P(E_2) = \frac{13}{52} $$
$$ P(E_3) = \frac{13}{52} $$

$$ P(E_1|E_2E_3) = \frac {P(E_2E_3|E_1)P(E_1) }{ P(E_2E_3)} $$
So this 
$$= \frac{(\frac{12}{51} \cdot \frac{12}{51})(\frac{13}{52})}
{\frac{13}{52} \cdot \frac{13}{52}} = 0.2214$$

Is this correct?

Comment: so the probability is 0.12?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume that we are dealing from a thoroughly shuffled standard deck of cards.

All sequences of cards are equally likely.  Thus the required probability is the probability that the **third** card is a spade, given that the **first two** are spades. This probability is (clearly) equal to $11/50$.

**Comment**:  We can obtain the same result by using Bayes' Rule, and working quite a bit harder.  And in any complicated calculation, there is always the possibility of error. For example, the *idea* in the OP's calculation is correct. However, 
$$P(E_2E_3|E_1)=\frac{12}{51}\cdot \frac{11}{50}.$$
Also, the denominator should be 
$$P(E_2E_3)=\frac{13}{52}\cdot \frac{12}{51}\cdot\frac{11}{50}+\frac{39}{52}\cdot \frac{13}{51}\cdot\frac{12}{50}.$$
With these modifications, the OP's argument goes through just fine. After some cancellation, we obtain $11/50$.